# Pass arguments to WP_Widget construct via register_widget action hook

Tags: wordpress, class, widget, extends

Is it possible to pass additional arguments into a custom Wordpress widget when using the register_widget() function?
register_widget only excepts one argument - the target class name.

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', function() {
    register_widget("ID_Projects_Widget"); 
} );

class ID_Projects_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct([...])
    }
}
```

Fairly extensive searching to date has drawn a blank...

https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/passing-arguments-to-widget

https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/allow-ability-to-pass-parameters-when-registering-widgets

The logic behind the question?

We want to pass in an array containing the post_type name, ACF 'options' page id, etc etc that was registered in a previous class… the widget will only be used to offer user choices…

We really want to avoid using more and more GLOBALS - if that is possible…

Do we have our logic backwards? Does the widget come before the egg?

Comment: [link: Pass vars to inherited Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713073/pass-variables-to-extended-class)
[link: Inheritance parent construct ] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603469/php-how-to-pass-child-class-construct-arguments-to-parent-construct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By creating an additional Extension to the Extended Widget Class, Properties can be sent to the registered widget.

```
/*
 * Standard WP_Widget
 * https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_widget/
 */
class Actual_Widget extends \WP_Widget {

    // WordPress WP_Widget Class 
    public function __construct($args) {

// do stuff with $args

        parent::__construct(
        // extend WP_Widget as per codex
        );
    }

}

/*
 * Args passed to WP_Widget Class __constuctor for processing
 */

class Temp_Widget extends Actual_Widget {

    public function __construct($args) {
        $this -> args = $args;
        parent::__construct( $this -> args );
    }

}

/*
 * Args passed via Action Hook to Temp_Widget Class
 */
add_action( 'widgets_init', function() {

    $args = array( 'chicken', 'fish' ); // Proceedural
    $args = $this -> args; // Or Class Properties

    $widget = new Temp_Widget( $args );
    \register_widget( $widget );
} );
```